# How to add bcc or cc in magento

Tags: magento

I don't know how to add cc or bcc in the following codings .. I tried bcc but mail can't go. Please some one help!..

The codes are

```
$data = array('name' => $username, 'to_user_id' => $to_userid, 'email' => $email, 'telephone' => $telephone, 'title' => $title, 'ip' => $ip, 'message' => $message);

            $templateId =1;
            $sender = Array('name' => "Admin", 'email' => "webmaster@example.com");
            $useremail = $product_user;
            $emailName = $username;
            $vars = array('username' => $username, 'telephone' => $telephone, 'mail_id' => $email, 'title' => $title, 'message' => $message, 'object' => $this);
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            $mailSubject = 'mail check';
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId))
                ->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)
                ->setBcc('zzz@gmail.com')
                ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $useremail, $emailName, $vars, $storeId);
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                $model = Mage::getModel("contacts/contacts")->setData($data)->save();


            Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addSuccess("You have been successfully sent your mail..");
            $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use `addBcc('zzz@gmail.com')` instead of `setBcc('zzz@gmail.com')` in your code or modify your code like this

```
//mail transaction
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$mail->getMail()->addCc('zzz@gmail.com');
$mail->addBcc('zzz@gmail.com')
    ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId))
    ->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)
    ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $useremail, $emailName, $vars, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Mage_Core_Model_Email class` does not support bcc (or cc). You need to override the send method and add this code right before `$mail->send();`.

```
if ($this->getBcc()) {
    $mail->addBcc($this->getBcc());
}
```

After that your code can be:

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
            ->setToName($senderName)
            ->setToEmail($customerEmail)                    
            ->setBody($processedTemplate)
            ->setSubject('Subject')
            ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
            ->setFromName($senderName)
            ->setType('html')
            ->setBcc('test@example.com') //bcc line added
            ->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add BCC to Magento Contact Us.

Go to Admin Panel->System->Configuration->Contacts. You are able to see Send Email To in Email Options section. Now, if you want to add Send Email BCC to this section.

1. copy contacts extension folder from app/code/core/Mage/Contacts to paste app/code/local/Mage/Contacts.
2. Open app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml (Go to line No: 360) change the code pool core to local.

   `<Mage_Contacts>
       <active>true</active>
       <codePool>local</codePool>
       <depends>
           <Mage_Core/>
       </depends>
   </Mage_Contacts>`
3. Open app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml, and find below code(Line 67)

   `<recipient_email translate="label">
       <label>Send Emails To</label>
       <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
       <validate>validate-email required-entry</validate>
       <sort_order>10</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
       <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
   </recipient_email>`

Add below code after above code in system.xml

```
<recipient_email2 translate="label">
        <label>Send Emails BCC</label>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>11</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </recipient_email2>
```

4. Open app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php (Go to line: 37) add below code.

   `const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT2 = 'contacts/email/recipient_email2';`

Then Go to line number: 94 and find below code.

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );
```

Then replace with below code:

```
$bcc_str = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT2);
                $bcc_email = explode(",", $bcc_str);

                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->addBcc($bcc_email)
                        ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                        ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                        ->sendTransactional(
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE), Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER), Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT), 
null, 
array('data' => $postObject));
```

5. Flush magento cache and check Admin Panel->System->Configuration->Contacts. Now you are able to see Send Emails BCC in Email Options section.