# add CC or BCC to Magento Community Contact form

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, contact-form

referring to this thread: [How to add bcc or cc in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679036/how-to-add-bcc-or-cc-in-magento/51149678?noredirect=1#comment89282991_51149678)

kindly note i test it on my Magento Comunity Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 but didnt work and its really important to me to have Copy and Blind Copy once the end user hit the submit button in my website contact form : https://www.khouryhome.com/contacts

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on [magento.stackexchange.com](http://magento.stackexchange.com) instead?

Comment: You need to make this question your own. Make it about programming. And make it easy for someone to answer.

Comment: dear in the other thread, i said i am new to this and i need help; no need to close my question without having any correct answers or at least some solution for my request. contact form in Magento community have send emails to: one email account; what i need is to add many emails as much as i want; it it so difficult to answer?

Comment: It's not difficult to answer, but you need to make an effort in asking a question that is about a programming issue. Not a request for code. You need to take the effort to ask a good question. At the moment there is nothing about your question that is strictly programming-related. You because the answer is not difficult and just because the answer is programming related doesn't mean you've asked a good programming question. Please fix it.

Comment: of course its programming and coding issue since from the backend of Magento you cant set many email address from the "send email to" field; so there is some file needs to be change in the CPANEL under app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php to be able to notify many email addresses once a submit button is triggered from the front end of the website. if you can help it would be great, if no just let it go please.

Comment: Please put the code that you're asking about in your question. Explain what's wrong with it, what you want it to do, etc. Then it's about programming. Right now you're asking for someone to write code for you. That's not a programming-related question.

Comment: The reason you don't have an answer yet is that you haven't done the hard work to write a good question.